# T-SQL How to grant role to user with ADMIN/GRANT option in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

After creating roles and granting privileges to them, I want to grant the privileges of a specified role to a user with grant option so that the user can grant privileges to others, how to do with it?

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'sabertazimi'
```

Doing like this can't make 'sabertazimi' to grant his privileges to others.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific code you used in the question you cannot use `WITH GRANT OPTION` which is normally used to grant privilege so the the user can grant same to other users.

For details and example see this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql

> Permissions
>
> Adding members to flexible database roles requires one ofthe
>   following:
>
> - Membership in the db_securityadmin or db_owner fixed database role.
> - Membership in the role that owns the role.
> - ALTER ANY ROLE permission or ALTER permission on the role.
>
>   Adding members to fixed database roles requires membership in the
>     db_owner fixed database role.

For privileges using `GRANT` statement see these links:

- https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/04/03/sql-server-difference-between-grant-and-with-grant/
- http://sqlity.net/en/1884/grant-option-delegate-permission-management/
- http://sqlity.net/en/1893/grant-using-grant-grant-option-roles/

Answer (score 0):

As we know:

> *The GRANT ... WITH GRANT OPTION specifies that the security principal receiving the permission is given the ability to grant the specified
>   permission to other security accounts.*

When the principal that receives the permission is a **role** or a **Windows group**, the AS clause must be used when the object permission needs to be further granted to users who are not members of the group or role. *Because only a user, rather than a group or role, can execute a GRANT statement*, a specific member of the group or role must use the AS clause to explicitly invoke the role or group membership when granting the permission.

The following example shows how the WITH GRANT OPTION is used when granting to a role or Windows group.

```
-- Execute the following as a database owner  
GRANT EXECUTE ON TestProc TO TesterRole WITH GRANT OPTION;  
EXEC sp_addrolemember TesterRole, User1;  
-- Execute the following as User1  
-- The following fails because User1 does not have the permission as the User1  
GRANT EXECUTE ON TestMe TO User2;  
-- The following succeeds because User1 invokes the TesterRole membership  
GRANT EXECUTE ON TestMe TO User2 AS TesterRole;
```

The full document can be read at this link:
[GRANT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Hope this help.